# What is the JVM initialization order for a class has an instance of another class

Tags: java, class, jvm, initialization

Suppose *JVM* has loaded the following `Foo` class for the first time and it's just passed to Linking step ( during resolution ).

```
public static void main(...) {
     new Foo();
}

public class Foo {

     private static int a = 4;
     private static Hoo hoo = new Hoo();

     Foo (){
         Log.i("Test", ">> Test foo's created!");
     }

}

public class Hoo {

     private static int b = 4;
     private static Soo soo = new Soo();

     Hoo (){
         Log.i("Test", ">> Test hoo's created!");
     }

}

public class Soo {

     private static int b = 4;
     private static Koo soo = new Koo();

     Soo (){
         Log.i("Test", ">> Test soo's created!");
     }

}

...
```

Now my question is this. We know that prior to completing child class construction, system calls recursively base/super class constructor(s). Does there exist some similar logic lies in the above code? I mean does *JVM* will complete the construction of `Foo` right after completing the `Hoo()` and `Soo()` construction ?

Thx.

Comment: What does your log tell you?

Comment: Definetly tells what I think. But I wanted make myself sure if some tricky or exceptional stuff might occur during this recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean does JVM will complete the construction of Foo right after completing the Hoo() and Soo() construction ?

Basically ... yes.

According to [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

and so on.

In your example, this means that the classes will be initialized in the order `Koo`, `Soo`, `Hoo`, `Foo` and that the executing `new Foo()` expression in the `main` method will trigger this.

Things get a bit complicated (and nasty) if there are cyclic dependencies between the static initialization of different classes, but the JLS covers this edge case too.

Comment: Thanks. Can you a bit elaborate what might happen when there're cyclic dependencies ? Having null references for instance ?

Comment: Broad brush: code running as part of one classes initialization may see another classes statics in a partially initialized state.  What that means depends on the situation.

Comment: One additional note: Of course it may vary but in our case, they're loaded in the order they appeared but linked and initialized as you wrote.